# Importing scipy stats modules to get expected value of empirical distribution

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I want to fit every member of a list of data sets to a lognormal distribution. Then, I want to calculate the expected value of a function over each distribution. I've tried the following code and get the following error.

**Code**

```
   from numpy import *
   from scipy.stats import lognorm
   dists = map(lognorm,data)
   expectations = [dist.expect(r_[1,1],zeros(40,)) for dist in dists]
```

**Error**

```
  AttributeError: 'rv_frozen' object has no attribute 'expect'
```

Perhaps I'm reading [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) incorrectly, I though because `expect` is a method of `lognormal` it is available to frozen distributions.

What is the right way to call the methods such as 'expect' from a frozen distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see thread at

http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2012-August/032860.html

`expect` is not yet connected to frozen distributions. Either, use a distribution that is not frozen or use a helper function like

```
def expect(X, f, lb, ub):
    if hasattr(X, 'dist'):
        return X.dist.expect(f, lb = lb, ub = ub)
    else:
        return X.expect(f, lb = lb, ub = ub)
```

update:

Besides the problem with the frozen distribution, you need to check the methods of the distributions.
You need to use `.fit(data, ...)` to estimate the parameters.

You can calculate an expected value of a function using `expect`, the signature is here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.expect.html?highlight=expect#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.expect

Default of `expect` is the identity mapping that calculates the mean. But you can also get the mean directly form the distribution using either the `.mean` or the `.stats` method. This avoids the integration if there is an explicit expression for the mean.

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the [Scjipy Frozen Object](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.stats.distributions.rv_frozen.html), you see that `expect` is no method of it.

Try :

```
 from numpy import *
 from scipy.stats import lognorm
 dists = map(lognorm,data)
 expectations = [ lognorm.expect(  func, s, loc  ) for dist in dists]
```

( I do not know the functions options )

Comment: Doesn't the list comprehension you wrote just iterate over but never use the information in dists? I froze the variable to preserve the shape of the empirically-fitted distribution.

Comment: I don't have the kind of knowledge in stats to answer you  : you have to find what to put in func, s and loc ( I would guess the 's' stand for the distribution )

Comment: Mine is a CS point- the variable in the for loop is never passed as an argument to `lognorm.expect`.